# Estimating the cost of implementing security measures

Tags: risk-management

Are there good resources or good practices on how to estimate the cost for implementing security measures in a company? My purpose is to justify to management that they need to spend this amount to beef up the security of our company in our industry. I believe some sort of standardised risk management tool can help. Or is there any industry research reports out there that already illustrates an estimated amount for each industry in the market? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most accurate way is to carry out a risk assessment.

For example, work out the value of each asset you want to protect within your company. Value is the value to your company, not just the price to purchase it in the first place. For example, cost of implementation, cost of the data, the value to owners and users, and the value it has to attackers.

Work out the SLE (Single Loss Expectancy) for each asset:

```
SLE = value of asset * exposure factor
```

Exposure factor is the percentage of loss a realised threat would have.

Then work out the ALE (Annualised Loss Expectancy):

```
ALE = SLE * annual rate of occurrence (ARO)
```

ARO is the number of times a threat takes place per year (1 for once a year, 0.5 for once every two years, 2 for twice).

Adding these together should give you your budget per year that you should spend on security. There is no point in paying more to prevent than the cost to your company if they happen.

See the [IT Risk Management Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IT_risk_management#Risk_assessment) for formal methods and software that can help with this.

Answer (score 2):

**Security is about loss prevention, not profit**.

There are plenty of reports about how to calculate the ROI (Return On Investment) for a company (I even saw a PhD on that) but this usually ends up with some wild hand waving and I am still waiting, after running budgets of $MM, for some magical formula which would tell management that the investment is worth the price.

I am sorry not to have a reply which has that neat formula, but you are not likely to find one. Companies which have a short path between IT and profits may find some reasonable links, though. You could argue that if you make `x` $/s, a downtime of `N` seconds means `N*x` $ loss. A DDos protection solution will cost you this and that so if you expect to be DDoSed (this does not cost much) then the investment is maybe worth it.

You will find reports that state that an intrusion costs a company whatever big amount of dollars. This is true for direct costs (ie. you have to pay legal fines) but does not take into account (or, on the other side of the spectrum - grossly exaggerates) collateral costs. Putting a dollar value next to loss confidence is not easy either.

This is to say that you can google some reports ([ENISA](https://www.enisa.europa.eu/) has a good [introduction](https://www.enisa.europa.eu/activities/cert/other-work/introduction-to-return-on-security-investment)) but the budget discussions about security are usually belly dancing.